Does undecidability allow infinite number of algorithms for limited ranges?
Do I understand correctly that undecidability does not preclude the existence of an infinite number of algorithms that, in the limit, would be able to decide $x$'s membership in a set? Of course, this limit would not be an algorithm, since it would be comprised of an infinite number of instructions.
For example, let’s assume for argument's sake that primality was undecidable. It would mean that there is no single algorithm $P(x)$ that decides if a number $x$ is prime. However, this does not imply that we cannot have separate algorithms for different ranges of numbers, such as $[0,1000), [1000,2000), [2000,5000),\dots$

Unfortunately I think the answer is a trivial "yes".
Consider some undecidable set $S\subseteq \mathbb{N}$, which is necessarily countable, $S=\{s_0,s_1,s_2,\dots\}$.
Take $A_n$ to be the algorithm that returns "yes" iff the input is in $\{s_0,s_1,\dots,s_{n-1}\}$ (which is finite so decidable).
Then the limit of $A_n$ as $n\to \infty$ decides $S$.

Nice proof! I was thinking whether you could do this for Turing machines, but if S is ordered by how long machines run, then A_n does halt if it is in a subset.
